# update state with data return undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have one state called data that is empty object state={data:{}}  I called RestAPI updated state USING set state when I console log it returned the data in the correct format but data that I need is this.state.data.title.rendered it says undefined but in console log it has data 
Rest Api is like this:

```
{id:5,title:{rendered:"home is good"}}


fetch(`http://localhost/react-wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                const { title, fimg_url, content } = responseJson;
                this.setState({ title, fimg_url, content });
                this.setState({ data: responseJson })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
```

In rendered method `{this.state.data.title.rendered}` return undefined while `{this.state.title.rendered}` return correct

Comment: Have you tried this `{this.state.data && this.state.data.title.rendered}`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Maybe it is `undefined` before fetching from backend.

So you need to validate if it is okay to render it like below:

```
const { data } = this.state;

return (
  <div>
    { data && data.title && data.title.rendered
      && ( <h1>data.title.rendered</h1> )
    }
  <div>
);
```

Comment: I fetch data in component did mount docs say it will run after component render when i console log this.state.title and this.state.data 1st one has data at first rendered but this.state.data has empty object at first at second render it has data why is that i have setstate why is it giving me undefined

Comment: @RabinAwale Yes. That is why you need to validate in render function before componentDidMount is called.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
fetch(`http://localhost/react-wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                const { title, fimg_url, content } = responseJson;
                this.setState({ data: {title, fimg_url, content} });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
```